# Clipping Raster to Only within Polygon Areas

Tags: r, spatial, raster, r-raster

I am trying to use `leaflet` to overlay a clipped raster according to a large number of polygons.  However, the raster I'm using is very large and won't map, let alone re-project. I have a feeling that I'm not actually 'clipping' the raster at all. Any help on reducing raster size, or actually clipping the raster according to the polygons, would be appreciated.

```
project_shp <- gUnion(spgeom1 = area1,spgeom2 = area2)

cr<- crop(raster, extent(project_shp), snap = "out")
fr<- rasterize(project_shp, cr)
lr<-mask(x=cr,mask=fr)

lr<-projectRaster(lr,crs=("+init=EPSG:4326"))
```

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1.1 Gb

```
leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>%
    addPolygons(data= provincial,weight = 2, opacity = 0.8)%>%
    addRasterImage(data= lr, colors = lr$FBP_Fuel_Type1)
```

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1.1 Gb

Comment: R stores all files to memory, you're running out of memory perhaps...

Comment: There is no need to warp to longlat surely? Doesn't leaflet want it in web Mercator? Can you post the print summaries of each object?

Comment: R does not not store all files in memory, that is unhelpful misinformation. More likely the target projection is unreasonable, but at any rate the output can be diverted to file by projectRaster

Comment: I'm on a different computer right now, so I will post the print summaries tomorrow.  Thanks for all your help @mdsumner.  Do you know of any other way I can render this using leaflet?  It seems like this shouldn't be too hard.  All I'm looking to do is clip the raster according to the polygons and then display the result on a leaflet map that I can ultimately use interactively with shiny. hmmmm

Comment: There is no need to rasterize the shape for use with mask. It can be used directly `lr<-mask(x=cr,mask=project_shp)` Maybe that does save you some memeory. @mdsumner yes leaflet expects web-mercator for rasters (though it expects epsg 4326 for vectors).

Comment: (Ah, gosh projection stuff is so fundamental should be in core libs and sorted out consistency-wise, eh? ). 8)